# Set variables in python list comprehension

Tags: python, generator

If I have 2 or 3 of the same calculations done within a generator for each loop, is there a way to just set them as a variable?

A quick example would be like this:

```
#Normal
[len( i ) for i in list if len( i ) > 1]

#Set variable
[x for i in list if x > 1; x = len( i )]
```

Before anyone says `len( i )` would be so fast the difference would be negligible, I also mean for other calculations, using len just made it easier to read.
Also, if there is a way, how would you set multiple variables?

Apologies if it's been asked before, but I've searched around and not found anything.

Comment: As my understanding goes so far, the OP is basically trying to reduce the `func` calls from 2 to 1 in every iteration in the expression `[func(x) for x in list if func(x) > something]`. The penalty for calculating `func` could vary significantly for each such `func` call.

Comment: Common subexpressions are also a potential source of error, as is a cumbersome syntax. I often want to filter the output, rather than the input, and an explicit terse syntax for common subexpressions would make it more clear what's going on. Part of the problem? How do we agree on a syntax that is objectively better than a nested comprehension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to get around the expensive operation is to nest a generator in a list comprehension that simply acts as a filter, for example

```
def foo(x):       # assume this function is expensive
    return 2*x

>>> [j for j in (foo(i) for i in range(6)) if j > 4]
#                ^ only called once per element
[6, 8, 10]
```

Using analogous functions and variables to your example, you'd have

```
[x for x in (len(i) for i in list) if x > 1]
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, this way makes a lot of sense, surely though it'd be even better to move the `(foo(i) for i in range(6))` out of it too?

Comment: You cannot move that expression out, that is what is calling `len` on all your `i` in your example. The outer list comprehension takes the output of `len` for each element, then compares that to your criteria.

Comment: Is there any benefit here in mixing a list comprehension and a generator ? (say over "nested list comprehensions" / "nested generators" )

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Yes, the generator will only yield elements as they are called from the outer list comprehension one by one. A nested list comprehension would create a list all at once, then perform the outer list comprehension.

Comment: Sorry, I'd not read it properly misinterpreted the code aha, yeah I totally get it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Most implementations of Python do not, as you correctly surmise, have common sub-expression optimization, so your first expression would indeed call len(x) twice per iteration. So why not just have two comprehensions:

```
a = [len(x) for x in list]
b = [x for x in a if x > 1]
```

That make two passes, but only one call of len() per. If the function were an expensive one, that's probably a win. I'd have to time this to be sure.

Cyber's nested version is essentially the same thing.

Comment: _"Most implementations of Python do not, as you correctly surmise, have common sub-expression optimization"_ as a matter of fact, common sub-expression optimization does not seem to be performed in that particular case (at least in CPython 3.3.0). Given the OP data (sorry for inline code): `>>> def l(i):
...     global a
...     a += 1
...     return len(i)
... 
>>> a = 0
>>> [l(i) for i in my_lst if l(i) > 1]
[2, 2, 3]
>>> a
7
`  As you can see, my `l` function is called 7 times for a 4 elements list.

Comment: A function with side-effects would not be eligible for common subexpression optimization in any case.

Comment: is the optimizer able to distinguish between function having side-effect or not if they do not belong to the same module ?

Comment: A good C compiler will find such cases. Python would certainly be able to know that some of its own built-ins like len() are pure if it cared to add this optimization.

Comment: You're right. My first test was, well... stupid. FWIW, I've checked using the [`trace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) module and a function without any side effect. The result is the same. No sub-expression optimization: `1: def l(i):
    7:     return len(i)

    1: my_lst = [('30',), ('30', '125'), ('30', '127'), ('30', '125', '567')]
    5: [l(i) for i in my_lst if l(i) > 1]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer (may have to pick cyber's for the best answer though with it being first and similar, sorry :P), but I'm not quite understanding the comments. Do you mean in some cases the above method wouldn't actually work and it'd make no difference to the performance?

Comment: No, both my code and Cyber's will work fine. Sylvain's comments simply confirm my suspicion that they are necessary.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker even len() is not pure: it can be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

using `itertools.imap` in python2 will be an efficient way to do what you need and most likely outperform a generator expression:

```
[x for x in  imap(len, lst) if x > 4]
```